# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2-2x+4=0$ then the value of $\alpha^6+\beta^6$ is

Tags: calculus, quadratics

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2-2x+4=0$ then the value
>   of $\alpha^6+\beta^6$ is

I know that, here, $\alpha\beta=4$ and $\alpha + \beta = 2$ and use that result to find $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$ using the expansion of $(a+b)^2$
But how to find $\alpha^6+\beta^6$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2$ instead of $x^3$?

Comment: This doesn't work, because a cubic has 3 roots, not 2.  Or is it implied that one of them is repeated?

Comment: The ploynomial have $3$ distincts roots so which ones do you chose?

Comment: Let me confirm it, might be a mistake on question.

Comment: I'm sorry it was $x^2$. My printed version was a bit blurred.

Comment: In case you have edited your question I need to edit my answer also.

Comment: @R.Singh Thank you sir.

Comment: You are most Welcome!

Comment: Oddly, none of the posts below reaches the answer to your question and the one you accepted might be **the most useless one** to solve this. The approach suggesting to express $\alpha^6+\beta^6$ in terms of $s=\alpha+\beta$ and $p=\alpha\beta$ and then to plug the values $s=2$ and $p=4$ in the expression, works, but it is long and cumbersome. Much preferable here (and what the authors have in mind) is to note that the roots of the polynomial are $$1\pm i\sqrt3=2e^{\pm i\pi/3}$$ hence $$\alpha^6+\beta^6=(2e^{i\pi/3})^6+(2e^{-i\pi/3})^6=2^6\cdot(e^{2i\pi}+e^{-2i\pi})=2^6\cdot2=128$$

Comment: @Did, Your answer is the easiest and closest to my syllabus. Kindly post it as an answer and I'll accept it as answer for future readers. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From $\alpha^2-2\alpha+4=0$ we get that for $n\geq 0$ we have $\alpha^{n+2}-2\alpha^{n+1}+4\alpha^n=0$, and we have the same relation for $\beta$. Putting $u_n=\alpha^n+\beta^n$ and adding, we get that $u_{n+2}-2u_{n+1}+4u_n=0$ for all $n$. We have $u_0=2$, $u_1=2$, and now it is easy to compute $u_6$.

Comment: Nice general answer for problems like this. +1

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Here $\alpha^2=2\alpha -4$ and same for $\beta$, as they are the roots of the equation $x^2-2x+4=0$.

Now calculate the value of ${\alpha}^6$ and ${\beta}^6$ in terms of $\alpha^2 and \beta^2$. Then substitute their value again.

Comment: I think $a^2=2a-4$

Comment: oops... Sorry for the silly calculation mistake..

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:

$$[(a+b)^2-2ab)][((a+b)^2-2ab)^2-3a^2b^2]$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general:

$$\text{a}\cdot x^2+\text{b}\cdot x+\text{c}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{a}}\tag1$$

So, for your example we can set:

- $$\alpha=x_+=\frac{-\text{b}+\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{a}}\tag2$$
- $$\beta=x_-=\frac{-\text{b}-\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{a}}\tag3$$

Now, for your problem:

$$\alpha^6+\beta^6=\left(\frac{-\text{b}+\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{a}}\right)^6+\left(\frac{-\text{b}-\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{a}}\right)^6=$$
$$\frac{\left(-\text{b}+\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}\right)^6+\left(\text{b}+\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}\right)^6}{64\cdot\text{a}^6}\tag4$$

Comment: I find this solution the easiest.

Comment: @HGSur Is this some kind of macabre irony? Did you actually try to implement this suggestion? And what happened then?

Comment: @Did, I interpreted this answer in the following way : Finding the roots using the quadratic equation and then rising it to the power and adding. It's mundane but worked for this question.

Comment: @HGSur You mean, you really performed the Herculean task of expanding the sixth powers in (4), involving complex numbers and all? Wow... And which *actual value* did you get, once the dust had settled?

Comment: @Did I used this tool for finding the root and then powers : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1+-+i+sqrt(3))%5E6%2B(1+%2B+i+sqrt(3))%5E6

Comment: @HGSur Oh, so you did **not** solve this by yourself. Anyway, weren't you surprised by the simple looking final answer? This could/should have made you suspect some kind of mechanism was at work here...

Comment: @Did Yes and I can't actually use that tool for exam. Can you post your comment as a answer please ?